# Evaluate string in field calculator QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, string

Is there any way to evaluate a string as an expression in QGIS.  For example, I want to evaluate the string in Column 'hukg' as an expression.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eval('hukg')`

> Function [eval](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#general-functions) evaluates an expression which is passed in a string. Useful to expand dynamic parameters passed as context variables or fields.

Comment: I'd recommend making it more explicit by using `eval('"hukg"')` (double quotes for a column, and that in single quotes as a string).